# Is there a way to tell what branch a specific revision was merged from?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My work environment has people working on multiple projects in different development branches, called `xxx-dev`.  When something is ready to be tested, it gets merged into `test` .  No development is done in `test` at all. Every revision in `test` is simply revisions merged from another branch and then committed. I am aware this is not the standard convention, however it is how things are done here.

Is there a way for me to look at a revision in `test` and tell what `xxx-dev` branch it was merged in from?

Mergeinfo can tell me that revisions 1, 2, and 3 were merged from `xxx-dev`  into `test`, but from what I can tell, it can't tell me that revision 4 is the revision created in `test` which contains the changes from those revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this from the official svn book :

```
svn log -v -r 390 -g
```

Would give you this :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r390 | user | 2002-11-22 11:01:57 -0600 (Fri, 22 Nov 2002) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/my-calc-branch/button.c
   M /branches/my-calc-branch/README

Final merge of trunk changes to my-calc-branch.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r383 | sally | 2002-11-21 03:19:00 -0600 (Thu, 21 Nov 2002) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   M /branches/my-calc-branch/button.c
Merged via: r390

Fix inverse graphic error on button.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r382 | sally | 2002-11-20 16:57:06 -0600 (Wed, 20 Nov 2002) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   M /branches/my-calc-branch/README
Merged via: r390

Document my last fix in README.
```

The -g option also show all the revision that were put into the branch. If you remove it you'll only have information about that specific revision (i.e there, it is the r390)

Comment: I suppose I deserve an RTFM response now. I appreciate you helping out anyway.  I did look through the manual but I didn't look at log specifically.